# How can I split a single partition into three when it already has tons of data?

Tags: partitioning

I'm considering splitting a single partition into three [as per Rinzwind's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/98126/7146). That is, P1 for Ubuntu 11.10 (which I currently have installed), P2 for Ubuntu 12.04 (or the prerelease), and P3 for data.

The single partition currently has **lots** of media stored on it. Would it make sense to:

- free up enough space for P1 + P2
- create them (reduce the existing partition and keep the data there - the existing partition becomes P3)
- install the relevant releases of Ubuntu on P1 and P2 (how?)
- delete everything that isn't in `/home` from P3
- create `/home` subfolders on P1 and P2 and symlink them to subfolders on P3

Or is there an easier/better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - install the relevant releases of Ubuntu on P1 and P2 (how?)

Well, classical. Just install from CD, and when asked where to install, choose the partition of your choice.

> - create /home subfolders on P1 and P2 and symlink them to subfolders on P3

No. Where you get asked where to install what, you can declare to use partition xN as /home (without reformatting), and the system will *mount* the same home for both versions.

Backup important data before and just be concentrated at this point in the installation processes.

Comment: I didn't think it would be that easy! :)

Comment: -I- like my OS's seperated (not everyone agrees ;) ) Using the same /home/ for more than 1 OS I would advice against it. You never know what settings inside /home/ gets altered or changed between 2 systems where it affects both environments. I also (due to work) more than Ubuntu on my system ;)

Comment: You can use the same home partition easily if you use separate usernames on each system. I currently have 2 ubuntu installs, arch and a fedora install using the same home partition.

Comment: good one! :) worthy of a +1 :)

Comment: @xyzzyman: Using 2 usernames means, you don't share the data, so what's the advantage of a common home?

Comment: @Rinzwind: I used the same home in the update process, when I didn't trust the new version. But if it works, I wan't my settings, configurations, email and so on to be preserved. But I agree that it might lead to problems, when the old version doesn't write new settings or, even worse, in the new format. I mostly shifted in days completely to the new version.

Comment: @user unkown: it saves you 10Gb harddisc space ;) 1 thing for consideration: if you mess up something in 1 /home/{user}/ and you used those for BOTH OSes you might find yourself locked out of BOTH. If not diff. /home per OS at least use different users :)

Comment: Just 1 thing: if you do this I'd still advice symlinking the directories in /home/{user} and /home/{user2} to the data partition: same data, same icons for all users. Plus you are also backup the correct information (since the content is on the data partition)